# Why don't jobs in a Celery chain pass their result to next job when wrapped in a chord?

Tags: flask, redis, celery, jobs, eventqueue

I am using Flask with Celery to add tasks to my event queue powered by redis. Currently, I have a flask route that creates a celery chord, and runs it on the worker. The header of this chord is a chain, and the body is a group of chain (a bunch of chains that run concurrently). The issue that I am facing is that when the header chain runs, the result is not passed down to the next job in the chain, causing a TypeError for a missing argument. I have `ignore_result=False` set for all of the jobs, and that doesn't make a difference. This chain was working before I wrapped it in a chord.

Here are the jobs & a function that builds the chord:

```py
def enqueue_tasks_for_policy():

    chains = []
    for question in questions:
        chains.append(
            chain(
                job1.s(question), 
                job2.s(question), 
                job3.s(question)
            )
        )

    full_chord = chord(
        chain(
            job1.s(), 
            job2.s(),
            job3.s(), 
            job4.s()
        ), 
        group(*chains)
    )
    return full_chord

@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def job1(source: dict[str, str]):
    # doing stuff
    return json.dumps(jsonable_encoder(data))

@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def job2(result: str):
    #doing other stuff but should have result
    return json.dumps(jsonable_encoder(data))

... job 3/4
```

This is how I am setting up celery in my flask app

```py
def celery_init_app(app: Flask) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object({
        "broker_url": app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"],
        "result_backend": app.config["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"]
    })
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app
    return celery_app

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    cors = CORS(app)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    celery_init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(auth)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)
    app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')
    return app
```

I saw these important notes regarding chains: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chord-important-notes
But I'm not really sure what to make of it and would be very appreciative of some guidance. Thanks for your time